# Align right the text in button of popup menu in devexpress

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I don't know if it is okay to ask it here but i hope i can get a good response.

[image]

I just want to align the `button OK` in the right side and also i already change the properties of it to `right` from `default` but still when i run my project it stay always in the left side. Did i miss something? Or is there any better way to align my button inside `popup menu`?  can someone help me please.

this is the current output when i run my system.
[image]

and you can see that the button okay still in the left side.

Comment: What is the exact name of the control you are using? Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: @AlexB. winforms sir. Done editing my question :)

Comment: @Muj what controls have you added to your form. Describe explicitly all of them

Comment: @jambonick i added a `ribon control` then i attach the `popup menu` to 1 of the button of it. Then inside of `popup menu` there is a list of `controls`. Then i want that some of the `control` like `buttons` will be align in the right side of `popup menu`

Comment: @Muj Can you also show us a screenshot how the menu looks like on running? Also, normally when you add a button to popupmenu it automatically gets the same width with the menu, so what else do you want to display next to the button at the same line?

Comment: @jambonick check my revision sir

Comment: It is difficult for me to understand by your screenshot so I would like you to clarify this: is the button's width smaller than the menu's ? Because it is possible that if the widths are the same, it is the "OK" caption, not the button itself aligned to the left. In this case change Alignment won't make any difference because the button can't move to other position, but still you can try change text alignement

Comment: @jambonick maybe you are right because in `Alignment` properties it says that `Gets or sets the horizontal alignment of the item's link(s)` but i didn't see any properties like `text alignment` or any other properties that can represent `text alignment` I wonder if it is on properties or maybe need to figure it out with code?

Comment: @Muj you can easily check if the button has the same width with the menu, by focusing the button with the mouse and observe the highlighted area. Moreover if caption alignment is what you actually want, then it is a different issue and we will try to help you solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is an [TextOptions.HAlignment](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressUtilsTextOptions_HAlignmenttopic) property which is used by BarButtonItem.Appearance, BarButtonItem.ItemAppearance and BarButtonItem.ItemInMenuAppearance and has values Far,Center,Near. Still, it is not supported in all cases (as it is referred in Note section of the link) and I'm afraid the popupmenu is one of them, because it cannot be found in Designer, you can access it only by code. Also all my tries to change the value of property had no effect in caption alignment. My proposal is to add empty space in your caption in order to bring it to center, supposed your menu width will stay the same

Comment: Yah. I just used some trick like what you've said. I inserted an empty spaces to my caption so that it will look like in the center or align right. Anyway tnx to your effort for helping me finding a solution in my problem.